# Jmeter -- how to combine variable name & counter()

Tags: variables, jmeter, counter

I've got the following problem:

[image]

I do gather that ProductId variable is assigned with the first value and then only that value is used when I refer to `${productId}`.

I was trying to apply `${__counter()}` to reference name in RegexExtractor,
but then BeanShellAssertion fails to set the property.

How should I properly work this around?

Comment: Why dont you have 10 variables productID_1 to produtID_10 and then use it

Comment: it's a prototype now, so posting 10 products is fine, later I'll have 100, 1000, so wouldn't be that easy :)

Comment: are these productId returned in a single request of mutiple request...

Comment: multiple (one by one)

Comment: You can probably write the product ids to a file and read it as a csv in another threadgroup.

Comment: yeah, writing ids to a file would prob work. But isn't it easier just to create productId+[counter]? (if one knows how to implement it properly, of course ^^)

Comment: No the problem here is you have two different thread groups. So for communication between them you have to have a external media.

Comment: ${__counter()} does the trick, but I put it in the wrong place. Anyway, thanks a lot for your comments!

Comment: Cool this was new to me :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use __V() function in order to combine 2 variables.

I.e. if you have 2 variables like:

- `productId`
- `counter`

And would like to evaluate i.e. `${productId_1}`, `${productId_2}`, etc.

It should be as simple as:

```
${__V(productId${counter})}
```

Same approach applies to [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function:

```
${__V(productId_${__counter(,)})}
```

Demo:

[image: V function demo]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for comprehensive information on above and other functions

Comment: Wow, very handy! Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Dmitri T, @Yabko how I can set the properties using ${__V(productId${counter})} for later use in the other thread group? I tried something like this `JMeterUtils.setProperty("${__V(productId_${__counter(,)})}", vars.get("${__V(productId_${__counter(,)})}")); ` but it failed. What I am missing?

Comment: Thank you, I said, your explanation helped me solve something I was stuck on, I thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ProdGroup

1. please store the product Id property as prod_id_1, prod_id_2,...prod_id_n or according to you convenience

How to to that ?

in post processor "Parameters" section  use ${__counter(FALSE,)} and in the script part try getting that `String counter = arg[0]` and convert that to integer and store it to a script variable  by default arg[0] value is String

`int c= arg[0] as Integer` //this is groovystyle check in your way to convert as int

now `props.put("prod_id_"+c,"extractedfrom_response")`

BID:

1. In you Bid group add a user defined variable section add the variable
   "prod_id" and value is empty
2. Define a counter start with the same counter 1 and give counter reference name [if your counter value in prod group was 0 then here also it must start with zero]
3. script sampler convert all the props to the variables

   ```
   Enumeration e = props.propertyNames();

   while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
       String propertyName = e.nextElement().toString();

       if (propertyName.startsWith("prod_id_")) {
           vars.put(propertyName, props.getProperty(propertyName));
       }
   }
   ```

   With this you have converted properties to variables named prod_id_1 ...to ... prod_id_n
4. In http sampler user reference as ${__V(prod_id_${counterreference in step 2})}  will do your job

For each thread the counter will increment by default

user ${__threadNum}  or ${counter reference name} in sampler labels for debugging.

Hope this helps. Please let us know if still problem is there.

Comment: Thanks! I've almost finished doing this your way, but @Dmitri T pointed me again to the __counter() and it did solve the problem easier. But I'm grateful for your help.

Comment: Thanks it helped. Dimitri T is blaze meter and jmeter expert , we can always expect good suggestions and  simple solution for complex problems. Even i learned from this. Dimitri blogs are really good